# Xamarin cross platform app to redirect to main.storyboard

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I am currently developing a cross platform app using Xamarin Forms and can't quite get it to redirect ios to a storyboard after launch screen.

Does anyone know how to do this? Any help would be appreciated

Thanks
Pudsey

Comment: XF doesn't use storyboards - those are an iOS only concept.

Comment: Brill thanks! That explains why I'm having troubles 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StoryBoard` is not available in the Xamarin.forms project. It can be only used in the Xamarin.iOS project. You can see in the `FinishedLaunching` method in iOS project:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

It loads the `new App()` which is the class in the `Xamarin.forms` project and then load the `pages` there in `App` class. Both Android, iOS ,UWP apps share the UI, design, logic and etc in those pages. You can't redirect to `main.storyboard` at that time.

You can read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin-forms#how-xamarinforms-works) about how-xamarinforms-works.

Also, you can customize the appearance and behavior of Xamarin.Forms controls on each platform by using [custom-renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)

Comment: Brill thanks for the help, have you got any suggestions on how to make a cross platform app without having to hardcode it? I can code in c# but I prefer to use storyboard like features and then code actions for each button etc?

Comment: @pudseythebear No, you have to hardcode it in C#. There is no such thing like storyboard in Xamarin.forms. If the answer is helpful to you, can you please mark/accept it which will help more people with same problem?